# Indenting lines in an index

Tags: indentation, indexing

I'm typesetting the index for a book. When an entry covers more than one line I would like the lines after the first to be indented some small amount. Is there a simple way to do it by playing with the way paragraphs are indented?

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}

\usepackage[top=53mm, bottom=45mm, left=40mm, right=40mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\noindent arithmetic [VOL I] V, VII-VIII, IX, XIII, 1, 3-4, 39 fn.\,1, [VOL II] 70 fn.\,1, 73, 77-78, 83-84, 86-88, 95, 97-104, 109, 117,  119, 123-125, 139, 139 fn.\,2, 141-142, 146-147, 149, 151-152, 154, 155 fn.\,1, 156-157, 162, 168, 253, 255, 257, 265.\\

\end{document}
```

I'd like to indent at 83-84 and 151-152. The point is I would like it to happen automatically for a long index rather than add space by hand.

Comment: You should create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that community members can play with. This should start with `\documentclass` and end in `\end{document}`. It just makes it easier to tailor any solutions to your needs.

Comment: The standard classes are indenting the lines after the first line with 40pt. Check the documentation of your class or packages that are responsible for the look of the index.

Comment: I've added a MWE.

Comment: So are you writing the index by hand?

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use my [`idxlayout`](http://ctan.org/pkg/idxlayout) package to change the hanging indentation of `\item`s in a manually created `theindex` environment. Note that for a one-column index you have to add `\par` at the end of the last `\item` for the settings to take effect. In the following example, I've also added code to remove the "Index" chapter heading and header.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}

\usepackage[top=53mm, bottom=45mm, left=40mm, right=40mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[columns=1,hangindent=2em]{idxlayout}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\ila@prologue}{\chapter*{\indexname}}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\ila@prologue}{\@mkboth}{\@gobbletwo}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{theindex}
\item arithmetic [VOL I] V, VII-VIII, IX, XIII, 1, 3-4, 39 fn.\,1, [VOL II] 70 fn.\,1, 73, 77-78, 83-84, 86-88, 95, 97-104, 109, 117,  119, 123-125, 139, 139 fn.\,2, 141-142, 146-147, 149, 151-152, 154, 155 fn.\,1, 156-157, 162, 168, 253, 255, 257, 265.\par
\end{theindex}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thank-you.